# Extract and install Word 2003 standalone without full CD

Tags: installation, microsoft-office

Given a proper Office 2003 CD, is it possible to extract just the files that are needed for one application... i.e. Word or Excel?

Browsing the CD, you can see `WORD11.MSI`.

The goal here is to extract just the necessary bits to install the one app. Disk space isn't the concern, but rather the larger question of 'is it possible' and how?

Is it possible to copy those files from the CD to another location to allow the installation of just one application?

What files would be required from the CD to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

What is your goal? Why not just copy all the files? HDD space is cheap these days, a few extra hundred MB isn't going to hurt anything.

Comment: Hi Davr. Thanks for the answer. The goal isn't to save on disk space, but concerns around extracting just the one app. I'll update the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but why? You still didn't answer why this is what you want to do. If you have an actual purpose, you may get better help, versus just a purely theoretical question.